# How do I move the input boxes in a sign in form closer together?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="Login">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" id="Full Name">  
       <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="Password">  
       <a href="#" class="forgot">forgot password?</a>
       <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
    </div>
```

That's my code above but boxes are too far apart. I want them within a few px of each other. I have tried changing the margin and padding on my .css file with no luck. Here is my css below;

```
   .Login {
  background: #eceeee;
  border: 1px solid #42464b;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 242px;
  margin: 15px auto 0;
  margin-top: 6px;
  width: 288px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.Login h1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #f1f3f3, #d4dae0);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a6abaf;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #727678;
  display: block;
  height: 43px;
  font: 600 14px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center; 
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 1px 0 #fff;
```

what do I code do I need to change or add to make them closer?

Thanks :)

Comment: Where is `h1`(.Login h1) tag? you need like http://jsfiddle.net/ewbtdr8h/ ?

Comment: Closer vertically or horizontally? Also, why are you applying `margin: 15px auto 0;`? In the next line, you replace margin-top then. This looks like someone has no idea of what he is doing...

Comment: maybe so http://jsfiddle.net/4qjvsrt2/

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a little bit

```css
   .Login {
  background: #eceeee;
  border: 1px solid #42464b;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 242px;
  margin: 15px auto 0;
  margin-top: 6px;
  width: 500px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align:center;
}
.Login h1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #f1f3f3, #d4dae0);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a6abaf;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #727678;
  display: block;
  height: 43px;
  font: 600 14px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center; 
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 1px 0 #fff; }

.submit, .password {
  margin-left:-3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Login">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" id="Full Name">  
       <input class="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="Password">  
       <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Sign In"><br><br>
  <a href="#" class="forgot">forgot password?</a>
    </div>
```

(Just press Run snippet)

Comment: nothing yet i want to know if he wanted to do such thing. I mean this is not a good way/style to make a log in content.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the input boxes to be closer, you just have to add a negative margin.

```
.Login > input {
    margin-right: -3px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/do6qhg74/

Or you use float to position the elements next to each other:

```
.Login > input {
    float: left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3eq7jwwk/